# $ionicLoading content doesn't show

Tags: ionic-framework

I try this code to show loading message like below but there is only loading animation appears without the message in content. How can I fix this?

```
$scope.show = function() {
  $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Loading feed...'
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content property should be renamed to template as shown here:

```
$scope.show = function() {
  $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading feed...'
  });
};
```

Here is the place where this is described in the docs:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/